# exit function gets skipped in Unix Shell script

Tags: unix, if-statement, exit

I have the following as part of my code. But when it reaches this **if** block, if the condition evaluates to true, the print function is getting executed but the **exit** function is not. It just gets skipped. Is it because of some mistake in the if condition? Or will I have to share my full code?

```
if ( grep -i ERROR /tmp/swm_pkg_ros )
then
            print "\nFailed. ...EXITING"
            print "\n....you will need to fix the problem and rerun\n"
            exit
else
            print "Successful"              

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
if ( grep -i ERROR /tmp/swm_pkg_ros )
then
            echo -e "\nFailed. ...EXITING\n....you will need to fix the problem and rerun"
            exit 1
else
            echo "Successful"
fi
```

you may print exit code `echo $?`

Comment: will adding exit code make any difference except to check status later?

Comment: We add different exit codes to differ reason of exiting. It doesn't make difference in functionality.

Comment: Yea, I know that. As far as I know it won't make any changes in functionality. Anyway thanks for your help